# Charge produces electric field and magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism

When does a charge produce:
1) only electric field
2) both electric field and magnetic field
3) electric field,magnetic field and radiations

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE! Homework-like and check-my-work like questions should ask about a specific physics concept and show some effort to work through the problem. We want our questions to be useful to the broader community, and to future users. See [How do I ask homework questions?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [Are check-my-work questions on-topic?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

1) A charge always produces an electric field

2) A charge produces a magnetic field when it is moving

3) A charge produces radiation when it is accelerated

Comment: okay so how do u particularly differentiate between moving and accelerated i mean i read it produces electric field and magnetic field in unaccelerated motion. What is unaccelerated motion?

Comment: Unaccelerated motion is when the charge has constant velocity i.e. constant speed and direction.